# How to format a TimePicker to 24 hours. "00:00" Flutter

Tags: flutter, time, timepicker

I want to apply formatting to a time that the `TimePicker` gives me, since it gives me `13:30`, but when I want to print it I get `1:30 PM`, and I want it to give me `13:30` only.

I attach the code of the `_pickTime`:

```
//Función que muestra el Time Picker.
  _pickTime() async {
    TimeOfDay? timeRecord = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: time.replacing(hour: time.hourOfPeriod),
      
    );
    if (timeRecord != null) {
      setState(() {
        finaltime = time.format(context);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package

```
         var df = DateFormat("h:mm a");
         var dt = df.parse(timeRecord!.format(context));
         print(DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dt));
```

so your function would look like

```
  _pickTime() async {
TimeOfDay? timeRecord = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: time.replacing(hour: time.hourOfPeriod),
  
);
  if (timeRecord != null) {
  setState(() {
       var df = DateFormat("h:mm a");
       var dt = df.parse(timeRecord!.format(context));
       var finaltime =  DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dt); 
      //print(finaltime)  
      // this will return 13:30 only
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.

And use this before you print

```
DateFormat.jm().format(paste your yourdatetime here)
```

Comment: It does not work for me, since it is of type ```TimeOfDay``.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).

```
    final dateNow = DateTime.now();
    final date = DateTime(dateNow.year, dateNow.month, dateNow.day, finalTime.hour,   
                   finalTime.minute);
    final timeStringFormatted = DateFormat(DateFormat.HOUR24_MINUTE)
                            .format(date);
```

Comment: It does not work for me, because ```finaltime``` it is of type ```TimeOfDay```.

Comment: I have just updated my answer, check it please.